# Upgraded to Xcode 7.1 - "Google Mobile Ads" framework not found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have upgraded to Xcode 7.1 from 6.4 beta. Before the update, I used the "Google Mobile Ads" framework for my previous version of Xcode. After the upgrade, my project is telling me that there is "no such module 'GoogleMobileAds'".  I use swift, if that matters at all.

Attempts:

- I have updated to the latest version of AdMob
- This Thread: [AdMob 7.3.1 and Swift 2.0 - Module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876363/admob-7-3-1-and-swift-2-0-module-not-found) . 1) I put my admob on my desktop in a folder: framework search paths = $(inherited)/users/me/desktop/folder/folder/FolderOfGooogleMobileAdFramework 2) enabling bitcode 3) changing framework search path to $(inherited)
- This Thread: [Getting error "No such module" using Xcode, but the framework is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there) 1) Google Mobile Ads is placed in a folder and set the framework search path to $(SRCROOT) and set it to recursive.

I clean and build constantly, and so far no luck.

EDIT: I have upgraded the syntax to Swift 2 syntax and still have this issue.

I have been researching for a while and I'm kind of at a loss right now. Would anyone have any ideas? I feel like it may have to do with the paths, I'm not sure.

---

EDIT - Debugger:

2015-10-27 15:24:36.823 MyProject[704:10002] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-10-27 15:24:36.824 My project[704:10002] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in UIKit/UIView.h may also be helpful.

Comment: You have to update to Swift 2 syntax. What are the errors you get after running the migration?

Comment: I ran through the project with upgraded syntax, and well, turns out it now functions the same way with the old syntax of Xcode 7.1.  Strange.  However, it still says "No such module 'GoogleMobileAds'" in all of my swift files that have that import.

Comment: Did you install it manually? Are you using CocoaPods or Carthage?

Comment: I am new to Swift and Xcode so I believe I have installed it manually, since I've never heard of either of those two.  When it came to Xcode 6.4 beta, I just take the googlemobileads framework and drop it in the "link binary with libraries" and I'm good to go.  Now with the updated 7.1, it seems to be a different story rather than "just drop it in".

Comment: UPDATE: If I do add the "googlemobileads" in a framework in a folder where my project is, I can run the code but the app crashes at the splash screen.  When it crashes, Xcode redirects to the debug navigator with a message at the bottom saying: self =(MyProject.ViewController) and all this weird stuff.  Very confusing...

Comment: UPDATE 2: I am able to make a project using the googlemobileads framework without a problem.  Just this project after the switch-over has some strange issue.  I really hope I do not have to start from scratch.

Comment: Let's go back to the one that is building with the framework, then crashing. That's progress! What's the full error message that prints in the console?

Comment: Good to know that I may be getting somewhere haha.  I have absolutely no idea how to read the console, so here's a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/7NLT6KW.png I assume it's just not cooperating with my ViewController.swift file?  EDIT: hold on that may not be the console, let me try to get a screenshot of that "bubble with the lines" icon

Comment: nvm, I think that is it actually

Comment: The debug console is at the bottom where it says (lldb) in your screenshot. If you hit the play button in the small toolbar directly above it (or type `c` at the lldb prompt) it should continue execution and print the error message. Might take a few tries.

Comment: Ok!  So I ended up hitting the play button a few times in the debugger until my app finally showed up (progress!), but I didn't notice anything in the console.  Once I clicked a button in my main menu, then a message popped up in the console.  I put that debugger error message in my original post... So what exactly does it mean by "constraints"?  I stripped my main menu's swift file bare, but the same message showed up.  What may it be?

Comment: Sounds like you have an exception breakpoint turned on (you can disable that), and your auto-layout constraints are invalid (probably unrelated to the Xcode 7.1 migration)

Comment: Oh my god hahah.  How did that breakpoint even get there?  I even found a few more of them in my other swift files, wow.  It works and I feel dumb.  Thank you Aaron for your help!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an exception breakpoint turned on (you can disable that), and your auto-layout constraints are invalid (probably unrelated to the Xcode 7.1 migration).